# Deploying cakephp application onto server

Tags: php, cakephp

my config/database.php is as follows,

```
var $default = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'ftp.example.sg ',
    'login' => 'xxx',
    'password' => 'xxx',
    'database' => 'testdatabase',
    'prefix' => '',
);
```

How can I make it deploy onto the server? What should be the value for host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put "localhost", it should be fine, at least for me :D

Comment: I changed it to 'host' => 'localhost', but when accessing the webpage, it is loading really slowly. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

It depends where the MySQL server is, if its on the same server just use `localhost`. Otherwise put in the mysql servers IP address or hostname.

Comment: +1. This should be the best answer :)

Comment: I changed it to 'host' => 'localhost', but when accessing the webpage, it is loading really slowly. What could be the problem?

Comment: @user448402: Its very hard to tell, it could be your script, your host or your internet speed.